# Mongoid::Errors::MixedRelations in AnswersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

Getting following error msg while saving an answer:

Problem: Referencing a(n) Answer document from the User document via a relational association is not allowed since the Answer is embedded. Summary: In order to properly access a(n) Answer from User the reference would need to go through the root document of Answer. In a simple case this would require Mongoid to store an extra foreign key for the root, in more complex cases where Answer is multiple levels deep a key would need to be stored for each parent up the hierarchy. Resolution: Consider not embedding Answer, or do the key storage and access in a custom manner in the application code.

Above error is due to the code **@answer.user = current_user** in AnswersController.

I want to save the login username to the answer which is embaded in question.

deivse User model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers
```

---

```
class Question

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Slug

  field :title, type: String
  slug :title

  field :description, type: String
  field :starred, type: Boolean

  validates :title, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 20, :allow_blank => false }

  embeds_many :comments
  embeds_many :answers

  #validates_presence_of :comments

  belongs_to :user

end
```

---

```
class Answer

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :content, type: String

  validates :content, :presence => true,  :allow_blank => false

  embedded_in :question, :inverse_of => :answers

  #validates_presence_of :comments

  belongs_to :user

end
```

---

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = @question.answers.create(params[:answer].permit(:answerer, :content))
    @answer.user = current_user
    redirect_to @question, :notice => "Answer added!"
  end
end
```

Using Rails 4, Ruby 2.2.2, Mongoid.

Comment: You mention `:answerer` in your controller, but I don't see this in your models. ALso, I don't understand why you have a `user_id` in your answer model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what the error message says.

Your Answer model is embedded in the question model. That is to say, you can only perform "normal" queries on the Question documents, and not on the models embedded in this one (actually you can, but it's more difficult and somehow kills the point of using embedded documents).

So you can get the user for a given answer, but not the inverse, which you have declared in your user model.

The simplest solution is to remove `has_many :answers` from the user model, but if you want to retrieve the list of answers for a given user, then embedding models is probably not the best solution: you should have relational models.

To make things clear, you should write `belongs_to :user, inverse_of: nil`

Comment: Thanks. Error resolved after modification you suggested. But current_user is not getting saved in the embedded answer document. Not sure what I am missing!!

Comment: That's because you are not saving it. When you do `@answer = @question.answers.create(params[:answer].permit(:answerer, :content))`, the `.create` will save your changes to the database (It's like doing calling `.new` and `.save`). So you want to call `@answer.save` after setting the answer's user